# Evaluation of $x^{y^{z}}$

Tags: exponentiation

Whether $x^{y^{z}}$ should be considered as $x^{\left ( y^{z} \right )}$ or $\left ( x^{y} \right )^{z}$, without any context?
If any one among these two is default consideration?

$\left ( x^{y} \right )^{z}$ appears more natural to me, but my calculator does it other way.

Comment: Why? $(x^y)^z$ is the same as $(x^{yz})$

Comment: If no particular parenthesis is given, you should consider this as $x^{(y^z)}$, you can recall the Fermat's number i.e. $2^{2^n}+1$, here no parenthesis is assigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual convention is  $x^{y^z} = x^{(y^z)}$ because if you want $(x^y)^z$ the equivalent expression $x^{yz}$ is simpler (no parenthesis required).